# Streaming PowerPoint file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpresponse

I am generating PowerPoint decks and then merging them on the fly and then streaming the resulting content via HttpResponse object i.e.

```
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=MasterPresentation.pptx;");
            response.BinaryWrite(masterPresentation.ToArray());
            response.Flush();
            response.Close();
```

Where **masterPresentation** is a MemoryStream object. When I open the downloaded Presentation in PowerPoint I get this message:

**PowerPoint found a problem with content in MasterPresentation.pptx. PowerPoint can attempt to repair the presentation.**

Upon repair everything seems fine no content corruption what so ever.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the differences between the generated file and the 'repaired' file?

Comment: @PhonicUK Yes I've tried comparing the files in OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool but it failed to open the corrupted file. Which other tool should I use to compare these files?

Comment: A hex editor of some variety.

Comment: http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question, In case anyone else needs to resolve this issue, all you need to do is replace:

```
        response.Flush();
        response.Close();
```

with

```
        response.End();
```

catching any exceptions and the resulting presentation will not be corrupted.

Comment: Yep. The "%officeProgram% found a problem with content in %ooxmlFile%. %officeProgram can attempt to repair the presentation." error message often happens when the containing zip file isn't properly terminated, even though the XML files contained within are perfectly fine.